# How to create object of Table type class in spring data cassandra

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

Table class

```
@Table(name="sampleTable")
public class sampleTable{

@PrimaryKeyColumn(type=PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED, value= "name")
    String name;
}
```

I have this class in a package outside of my class with my main method.

I am unable to get a reference of sampleTable even when I am using component scan on the package containing sampleTable class. How can I get a reference of sampleTable class.

Comment: Checkout the [getting started section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.getting-started) of the reference docs. RTFM is always a good start.

Comment: In the examples Table class objects are being created with new, I was wondering if we could create spring managed beans for the class

Comment: The only managed beans are `CqlTemplate`, `CassandraTemplate`, and repository instances. It makes no sense to have managed `@Bean SampleTable` because it's purely data.

Comment: So is using a new construct the best way to create SampleTable object or a prototype the best way to create the object